# iOS using both cameras at the same time?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there anything in the HIG or in Apples doc's that say that you cannot use the front camera and the back camera simultaneously at the same time to take a photo?  Or technically is this not possible because of some limitation?  Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is impossible and it is not allowed to access both simultaneously**

So you can not use both cameras at a time because as one camera begins, the other will stop.